# Consumir WebService asmx com Android

Tags: java, android, .net, web-service, asmx

Estou tentando pegar o SOAP provido de um webservice asmx local no meu emulador android. No meu PC o resultado é o seguinte:

[image: https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/eSiqMvXnThuCGrn4E6pk]

No emulador contudo, tentei abrir no seu navegador de duas formas:

Utilizando seguinte URL:

> 10.0.3.2:49498/WebServiceApp.asmx/ObtemListaProdutos

Demora um pouco para carregar e aparece o seguinte:

> "Webpage not available
>   The webpage at http://10.0.3.2:49498/WebServiceApp.asmx/ObtemListaProdutos might be temporalily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web addres"

Ou utilizando a URL a seguir:

> 10.0.2.2:49498/WebServiceApp.asmx/ObtemListaProdutos

Na hora já aparece

> "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
>   HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid".

Creio que se não funciona nem no browser do emulador, menos ainda na aplicação, correto?

Qual dos dois endereços (10.0.2.2 ou 10.0.3.2)está certo e o que está errado na chamada url?

Obrigado.

Comment: O exemplo que você mostrou usando o navegador do PC utiliza localhost. Tente usar o IP colocado no navegador do emulador e veja o resultado. Provavelmente você está com problemas na configuração do IIS.